# CNN classifier for cytometric data always has a similar accuracy, regardless of complexity, number of epochs or size of the layers

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, accuracy

**Background:**

I am making a convolutional neural network (CNN) to try and classify cytometric data. This data has a shape `(num_cells, num_markers)`. Additional information on using CNNs for cytometric data can be found here ([CellCNN](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms14825), [Deep Cytometric CNN model](https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.2003026117)). They are supposed to work much better than other methods (SVM, random forest, autoencoder ...).

**Dataset & data handling**

The dataset I am currently using has a shape `(172791, 24)`. I have ground truths for these cells. These ground truths basically tell me if the cells are sick or healthy. It is thus a binary classification problem. However, I also need to use a similar model later on a dataset with 3 classes and a different amount of markers, but to account for this in my network, this should just be changing a few parameters.

I split my dataset in an 80% train/20% test split. The train dataset is then split into an 80% train/20% validate split. I use the validate dataset to test the loss during each epoch and then after training I calculate metrics like accuracy scores and a confusion matrix using the test dataset.

**Model Design:**

I am using pytorch to create my model. I use a `CrossEntropyLoss()` criterion and as an optimizer, I use `Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1E-4, weight_decay=1e-5)` (weight decay in Adam optimizer in pytorch is apparently implemented as L2 regularisation).

I made a deep network containing 2 convolutional layers and 2 fully connected layers.
For the convolutional layers I use a 1D convolution since the cells (each row of 24 markers) are arranged randomly and have no correlation to each other. Each convolutional layer is followed by a `ReLu` activation layer and a batch normalization layer.
After the convolutional layers I use a polling layer (1D mean or max pooling).

For the first fully connected layer, I employ a `Linear` layer followed by a `ReLu` activation layer and a `Dropout` layer. The second fully connected layer then gives the output

**Problem:**

When I train the model and then use it on the test set, I get an accuracy of around 90% regardless of what I try. Admittedly this is definitely not bad. However, in literature (see the references in the background section) I find that CNNs should be a lot better at classifying cytometric data. I have also used a `HistGradientBoost` and an `SVM` algorithm on the data. Those models yield accuracies of around 98% - 99% after tuning their hyperparameters.

I have experimented with the following things:

- Different amounts of convolutional layers (1 - 3)
- Different amounts of fully connected layers (1 - 4)
- Using pooling after each convolutional layer instead of only the last
- Using no batch normalization
- Using different activation functions (this only yielded in lower accuracies)
- Using different output shapes (e.g. filter sizes) of the convolutional layers
- Using different sizes of the fully connected layers
- Using different values for the dropout layers

My metrics, a learning curve (train loss vs validate loss) and a confusion matrix, are shown below:
[image]

Now, it looks like the loss is still decreasing, which is true, however anything between about 3 and 50 epochs gives an accuracy of between 89% and 91%. After a few epochs nothing changes much which would lead me to believe that the model might be too complex, but i have tried reducing complexity which did not work. After more than 50 epochs the test score starts to increase again meaning we're definitely over-fitting by that point.

I am quite lost at this one. Does anyone have any ideas, suggestions or pointers as to what I could still try to increase the accuracy of my model. Or am I doing anything wrong. I admit that it's my first time designing a CNN (or any NN for that matter) so I might be misunderstanding something still.

Below I also provide my CNN implemented using pytorch for those interested:

```py
import torch.nn as nn


class CytometryCNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CytometryCNN, self).__init__()
        # Convolutional layers
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(1, 24, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv1d(24, 24, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        
        # batch normalization layers
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(24)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(24)

        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.pool = nn.AvgPool1d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        
        # fully connected layers
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(24 * 12, 64)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(64, 2)

        self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout(0.5)

    def forward(self, x):
        # Add a channel dimension shape (batch_size, n_features) -> (batch_size, 1, n_features)
        x = x.unsqueeze(1)

        # First convolutional layer
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.bn1(x)

        # Second convolutional layer
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.bn2(x)

        x = self.pool(x)

        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)

        # First fully connected layer
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.dropout1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)

        # Second fully connected layer
        x = self.fc2(x)

        return x
```

Thanks in advance!